# joomla 3.x tags in custom component fails

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

Running Joomla 3.3.0-dev

I'm following the info posted [here](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.2%3aUsing_Tags_in_an_Extension) about adding tag support to a third-party component.

I've added the content type to the `#__content_types` table and modified my `table` file like this:

```
class MycomponentTableElement extends JTable
{
    public $tagsHelper = null; // failed when protected and public

    public function __construct(&$_db)
    {
        parent::__construct('#__mycomponent', 'id', $_db);
        // Add Joomla tags
        JObserverMapper::addObserverClassToClass('JTableObserverTags', 'MycomponentTableElement', array('typeAlias' => 'com_mycomponent.element'));
        //$this->_observers = new JObserverUpdater($this); JObserverMapper::attachAllObservers($this); // failed with or without this line  
    }
```

I added the tag field in the `edit` template, and it worked fine-- but when I save an object I get the following error:

```
Save failed with the following error: Unknown column 'tagsHelper' in 'field list'
```

What am I missing? There's no other steps (besides front-end steps!) that are mentioned. It seems like I need to modify the model but that info is not applicable.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe it's because of beta version?
And I don't see code that you posted in that link.

Comment: It looks like an SQL error. Are you trying to save something to "tagsHelper" column in your database? Maybe somewhere in your code is messed up when using JHelperTags class.

Comment: @HungTran-- thanks, but that's the point. Joomla's tag helper is failing to parse / save the tags. There is no `tagsHelper` column, nor should there be one.

Answer (score 0):

"**This Page Needs Copy Editing**" and it's really true!

I also follow initial steps as described in page

- Register a 'Content type' for the extension view(s)
- Add 'Observer methods' to the extension table class(es)
- Add 'Tag fields' to the  extension edit forms

But to make field tag works on custom extensions I need to explicit set form field value in view file of backend:

```
$tagsHelper = new JHelperTags;

$this->form= $this->get('Form');

$this->form->setValue('tags', null, $tagsHelper->getTagIds( $this->item->id, 'com_custom.viewname') );
```

in this way on edit page all seems to work correctly.. surely exist better and more clean method, but until doc page will not be updated, this can help someone!

Answer (score 0):

1- Add tag field to your xml form file or edit template file

2- Modify `#__content_types` table file:

```
function __construct(&$db)
    {
        parent::__construct('#__ir_products', 'id', $db);
        JTableObserverTags::createObserver($this, array('typeAlias' => 'com_itemreview.product'));
    }
```

3- Modify model file getItem function:

```
public function getItem($pk = null)
    {
        $item = parent::getItem($pk);

        if (!empty($item->id))
        {
            $item->tags = new JHelperTags;
            $item->tags->getTagIds($item->id, 'com_yourcomponent.yourmodel');
        }
        return $item;
    }
```